# seprate object data via coma for every item but not last

Tags: java, android, string

**want a string for items in object separated by coma but not the last item**

```
 next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
                if (productList.get(i).isProductChecked) {

                    if (!multiId.contains(i))
                        multiId.add(i);
                    Product obj1 = productList.get(i);
                    String fname = obj1.getdescription();

                    List<String> productDescription newArrayList<String>();
                    productDescription.add(fname);


                    String join = productDescription.toString();

                        Log.e("SPLIT", join);

                } else {
                    if (multiId.contains(i))
                        multiId.remove(multiId.indexOf(i));
                }
            }
```

### Current Output

08-04 11:50:37.273 2114-2114/com.weenggs.flora E/SPLIT: [New Product2]

08-04 11:50:37.273 2114-2114/com.weenggs.flora E/SPLIT: [New Product3]

### Desired Output

New Product2,New Product3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is not a wishlist, nor "write-me-code" service.

Comment: so what is wrong with split ?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thank you for your kind words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

1.Declared a array list.

```
List<String> productPrice = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2.Stored a string object in that array list

```
fname = obj1.getPrice();
 productPrice.add(fname);
```

3.And in last used text utils for joining that array list items via comma.

```
android.text.TextUtils.join(",", productPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are :

```
String object = "apple,orange,banana"; //as you said, you should get apple and orange

object = object.substring(0, object.lastIndexOf(","));
String[] result = object.split(",");
```

**result** is the array includes all items in object except last item !

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1   [Log Error ] @FaridFaa

Comment: @JenishKeriwala would you plz send your string that you want to split it ?